# How do I choose 1 row like this with code without manually clicking it in "CBCGPGridCtrl"?

Tags: c++, mfc, bcg

I'm using `CBCGPGridCtrl` within `MFC`, but I don't know how to select row like this picture by code instead of manually clicking on the row using my mouse.

[image: image link]

Comment: You can not select the row if it is not added. You can instert 5 rows with blank space, and then select it.

Answer (score 0):

You select a row by calling the [CBCGPGridCtrl::SelectRow](http://help.bcgsoft.com/BCGSuite/class_c_b_c_g_p_grid_ctrl_a3d9805fe73fd04afe5077f46d7e97a46.html#a3d9805fe73fd04afe5077f46d7e97a46) class member.